# Действия внутри варианта в операторе case

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Что означает в скрипте запись ниже?
Объясните поподробнее:

```
case $key in
-d|--work-dir)
WORKDIR="$2"
shift #past argument
shift #past value
;;
...
esac
```

Весь скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

#echo $"==============="
#WORKDIR=$(dirname $(mktemp -u)) #"."
UUID=$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)

WORKDIR=$(mktemp) #"."
LOGDIR="./Logs"
LOGDROP=NO

DBHOST="localhost"
DATABASE="DAE"
DBUSER="root"
DBPASSWORD="1"

JOBS="0.8"

PROJECTSTYPE="*"
PROJECTNAME="*"

JOBSRECHECK="5"
JOBSBATCH="100"

DEFAULT=NO

#echo WORKDIR= "${WORKDIR}"
#echo LOGDIR= "${LOGDIR}"
#echo $"==============="


## worker_start.sh -d tmp - l

POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
-d|--work-dir)
WORKDIR="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-l|--log-dir)
LOGDIR="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-dh|--host)
DBHOST="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-db|--database)
DATABASE="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-u|--db-user)
DBUSER="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-p|--db-password)
DBPASSWORD="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-j|--jobs)
JOBS="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-ld|--log-drop)
LOGDROP="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-pt|--projects-type)
PROJECTSTYPE="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-pn|--projects-name)
PROJECTNAME="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-jc|--jobs-recheck )
JOBSRECHECK="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;
-jb|--jobs-batch )
JOBSBATCH="$2"
shift # past argument
shift # past value
;;

-def|--default)
DEFAULT=YES
shift # past argument
;;
*)    # unknown option
POSITIONAL+=("$1") # save it in an array for later
shift # past argument
;;
esac
done
#set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}" # restore positional parameters

#echo FILE EXTENSION  = "${EXTENSION}"
#echo SEARCH PATH     = "${SEARCHPATH}"
#echo LIBRARY PATH    = "${LIBPATH}"

echo ""
echo "Worker start with options:"


echo UUID= "${UUID}"
echo WORKDIR= "${WORKDIR}"
echo LOGDIR= "${LOGDIR}"
echo LOGDROP= "${LOGDROP}"

echo DBHOST= "${DBHOST}"
echo DATABASE= "${DATABASE}"
echo DBUSER  = "${DBUSER}"
echo DBPASSWORD = "${DBPASSWORD}"

echo JOBS  = "${JOBS}"

echo PROJECTSTYPE  = "${PROJECTSTYPE}"
echo PROJECTNAME  = "${PROJECTNAME}"

echo JOBSRECHECK  = "${JOBSRECHECK}"
echo JOBSBATCH  = "${JOBSBATCH}"

echo DEFAULT         = "${DEFAULT}"
#echo "Number files in SEARCH PATH with EXTENSION:" $(ls -1 "${SEARCHPATH}"/*."${EXTENSION}" | wc -l)
#if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
#    echo "Last line of file specified as non-opt/last argument:"
#    tail -1 "$1"
#fi

PYTHONPATH=. python worker_start.py --work-dir $WORKDIR --log-dir $LOGDIR -dh $DBHOST -db $DATABASE -u $DBUSER -p $DBPASSWORD -j $JOBS -ld $LOGDROP -pt $PROJECTSTYPE -pn $PROJECTNAME -jc $JOBSRECHECK -jb $JOBSBATCH -def $DEFAULT --UUID $UUID
```

Comment: Откуду вы это взяли?

Comment: У меня есть скрипт. Вытащил от туда.
Могу скинуть весь скрипт

Comment: Добавте прямо в вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/764110/edit). Ответ удалите.

Comment: Вас интересует наверное оператор case?   Наберите здесь в поиске - bash case.

Comment: С учётом полученого ответа поправте ваш вопрос. Где кнопка править вы уже знаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-d|--work-dir)
WORKDIR=%2
shift #past argument
shift #past value
;;
```

во-первых, не `%2`, а `$2`.

более полный пример:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] # пока количество оставшихся аргументов больше нуля
do                   # делаем в цикле:
  case "$1" in       # сравниваем первый аргумент скрипта
    -d|--work-dir)   # со строкой `-d` или строкой `--work-dir`;
      workdir="$2"   # если совпал, то присваиваем переменной `workdir`
                     # значение второго аргумента;
      shift          # удаляем первый аргумент (`-d` или `--work-dir`)
      shift          # опять удаляем первый аргумент (то, что поместили
                     # в переменную `workdir`)
    ;;               # конец обработки варианта, начинающегося с `-d|--work-dir`)
                     # дальше могут идти другие варианты
  esac               # конец оператора case
done                 # конец цикла `while`
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Никогда бы не подумал что это сравнение так пишется в Shell

Comment: @Денис Если вас ответ полностью устроил, не пишите комментарий типа "спасибо", отметьте ответ как принятый (это вы уже сделали) и можете добавить плюс (стрелка вверх слева от ответа).

Comment: *shift*, помещённый перед *done*, упрощает жизнь; замена *[[* на *[* даёт переносимость.